# SPF record issues

Tags: sendmail, spf

I'm desperately looking for some help with my setup. 
I recently set up my VPS server and installed sendmail on it.
All emails sent from the server end up in the spam folder with the message:

```
spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning user@hostname.com does not designate 1.2.3.4 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=user@hostname.com
```

and:

```
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning user@hostname.com does not designate 1.2.3.4 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=user@hostname.com
```

My SPF record value is:

```
v=spf1 mx a ptr ip4:1.2.3.4 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

running `host 1.2.3.4 on my server returns server1.hostname.com`

Not sure if it matters or not, my MX records are:

```
MX (10)  mxl1.spamora.net
MX (10)  mxv1.spamora.net.
MX (10)  mxp1.spamora.net.
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you mail sources and SPF line up. the IP it reports (which I assume is not really `1.2.3.4`) needs to be listed either explicitly as an `ip4` mechanism, or via an IP range covered by an appropriate `include`. The `softfail` result means it's falling through all the way to the `~all` default, i.e. it does not match any of the previous mechanisms. We can't test any of this for you without real values.

It's best to put `ip4` mechanisms first as they are fastest for receivers to resolve (don't need any DNS lookups).